# Ag-Grid how to display Chart Toolbar in the standalone version

Tags: angular, charts, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

We are working with Ag-Grid and we have seen that they offer the Chart Toolbar in the integrated chart https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/integrated-charts-toolbar/#configuration-sidebar however we couldn't find it in the standalone chart edition. Is it actually supported for the standalone edition and if so how to enable it please ? If not do you know of any way to integrate that functionality?